# NullPointerException on TabGroupactivity when setting button typeface

Tags: java, android, tabs

I'm having a little problem with an activity I have loading in a TabGroupActivity

```
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.user_profile);

    f = new Functions();
   String  j = f.getUserInfo();

  arialFont = Typeface.createFromAsset(this.getAssets(),"Arial.ttf");  


  username = (TextView)findViewById(R.id.txtProfileName);
  firstname = (TextView)findViewById(R.id.txtName);
  Address1 = (TextView)findViewById(R.id.txtAdd1);

  Cit = (TextView)findViewById(R.id.txtCity);
  PostCode = (TextView)findViewById(R.id.txtPost);
  Coun = (TextView)findViewById(R.id.txtCountry);
  Phon = (TextView)findViewById(R.id.txtPhone);

  dob = (TextView)findViewById(R.id.txtDOB);
  gender = (TextView)findViewById(R.id.txtGender);

  yourDetails = (Button)findViewById(R.id.Button01);
  payment = (Button)findViewById(R.id.Button02);
  billing = (Button)findViewById(R.id.Button03);
  history = (Button)findViewById(R.id.Button04);

  yourDetails.setTypeface(arialFont); <-- Null Pointer exception starts here
  payment.setTypeface(arialFont);
  billing.setTypeface(arialFont);
  history.setTypeface(arialFont);

  try {
    parseData(j);

} catch (JSONException e) {
    // TODO Auto-generated catch block
    e.printStackTrace();
}
```

The error I recieve from the code is this:

```
02-27 13:22:47.278: E/AndroidRuntime(929): Caused by: java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start activity ComponentInfo{com.Ticketline.Ticketline/com.Ticketline.Ticketline.UserProfile}: java.lang.NullPointerException
02-27 13:22:47.278: E/AndroidRuntime(929):  at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:1955)
02-27 13:22:47.278: E/AndroidRuntime(929):  at android.app.ActivityThread.startActivityNow(ActivityThread.java:1796)
02-27 13:22:47.278: E/AndroidRuntime(929):  at android.app.LocalActivityManager.moveToState(LocalActivityManager.java:135)
02-27 13:22:47.278: E/AndroidRuntime(929):  at android.app.LocalActivityManager.startActivity(LocalActivityManager.java:347)
02-27 13:22:47.278: E/AndroidRuntime(929):  at com.Ticketline.Ticketline.TabGroupActivity.startChildActivity(TabGroupActivity.java:61)
02-27 13:22:47.278: E/AndroidRuntime(929):  at com.Ticketline.Ticketline.Account.onCreate(Account.java:33)
02-27 13:22:47.278: E/AndroidRuntime(929):  at android.app.Activity.performCreate(Activity.java:4465)
02-27 13:22:47.278: E/AndroidRuntime(929):  at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1049)
02-27 13:22:47.278: E/AndroidRuntime(929):  at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:1919)
02-27 13:22:47.278: E/AndroidRuntime(929):  ... 18 more
02-27 13:22:47.278: E/AndroidRuntime(929): Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException
02-27 13:22:47.278: E/AndroidRuntime(929):  at com.Ticketline.Ticketline.UserProfile.onCreate(UserProfile.java:83)
02-27 13:22:47.278: E/AndroidRuntime(929):  at android.app.Activity.performCreate(Activity.java:4465)
02-27 13:22:47.278: E/AndroidRuntime(929):  at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1049)
02-27 13:22:47.278: E/AndroidRuntime(929):  at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:1919)
02-27 13:22:47.278: E/AndroidRuntime(929):  ... 26 more
```

I know the issue is with setting the buttons typeface to Arial, the problem is I don't understand why this is an issue. If I comment the setTypeface lines out it works fine and will move onto other activity which do have their button typefaces set within the TabGroupActivity which perplexes me even more.

Top marks for anyone that can explain this to me

Comment: Is it possible that yourDetails is null on line 83?

Comment: In order to verify if its related, you can call some method in yourDetails after you remove the setTypeface call. This way you can know its not related, and probably its an error with findViewById.

Comment: Figured the issue out, the coder who worked on this app before me gave the history button the id "btnHistory" instead of "Button04". Naturally this resolved in a null pointer error. Massive thank you for pointing me in the right direction

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Figured the issue out, the coder who worked on this app before me gave the history button the id "btnHistory" instead of "Button04". Naturally this resolved in a null pointer error because the id "Button04" doesn't exist in that activity.

Comment: I'm glad you got it figured out. I would strongly suggest making those button names more descriptive as the coder before you did. When you get a lot more code going on it will save you a lot of headaches because `btnHistory` is a lot easier to remember for a History Button than `button04`. Totally up to you but having a standard naming convention will help you a lot

Comment: Thanks for the advice, I'm doing that as I go along. Theres alot of functionality that I need to strip out and add in so naturally theres alot of build up of random names. I will be alot more descriptive with my names in future.